# How to use GIT on linux server with limited rights

Tags: linux, git

I want to use git to transfer code between my account on a cluster and my work computer.

The cluster already has a git installation, but I can't get it to clone? The recommendation seems to be to use https, and a good first step seems to be to try to update git?

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
Cloning into 'git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
```

As I understand it, git is trying to write to a .crt file, but can't?
I suspect an issue could be that I don't have write access to /etc/ssl/certs? if so, what is the workaround?

For reference, in case this info is important:

```
git --version
git version 1.8.3.1

cd /etc/ssl/certs
ls
ca-bundle.crt  ca-bundle.trust.crt  make-dummy-cert  Makefile  renew-dummy-cert
```

I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Git does not *write* certificates, and in fact, Git itself doesn't even read them: it just relies on the (usually-system-provided) libcurl library to read them. Git 1.8.3 is very old though, which suggests that your system itself is also very old and might not speak modern SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/` contains system wide configurations and `/etc/ssl/` even quite sensitive ones. So it is absolute correct that you can not write there as a non-root user and `git` also won't try to write there. `git` *should* work as ordinary user just fine.

The error message however indicates that `git` is trying to read `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` for trusted CA certificates to verify the HTTPS connection is secure. But on your system this file does not exist, instead there is a `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` that `git` should probably use instead.
So this seems to be a configuration error.

You can manually specify the path to the CA info file with the [`http.sslCAInfo`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslCAInfo) configuration option:

```sh
git -c http.sslCAInfo=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt clone https://github.com/git/git

# or set the path in your global ~/.gitconfig
git config --global http.sslCAInfo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```

If this still won't work you can disable ssl verification completely with [`http.sslVerify=false`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslVerify) - **but this is a security risk!** Only do this if you know what you're doing and manually verifying the integrity of the cloned code.

Comment: I had to change -g to --global, but otherwise this worked :)

Comment: oh yes, that was wrong, I fixed it in the answer